# BeautifulSoup.find_all for nested divs without class attribute

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am working with python2 and I wanted to get the content of a div in html page.

```
<div class="lts-txt2"> 
   Some Content 
</div>
```

If the div class is like above then I can get the content using

```
BeautifulSoup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": 'lts-txt2'})
```

But if the div is like,

```
<div class="lts-txt2">
   <div align="justify">
      Some Content 
   </div>
</div>
```

then using

```
BeautifulSoup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": 'lts-txt2'})
```

isn't return the content.
So I tried with

```
BeautifulSoup.find_all('div', attrs={"align": 'justify'})
```

But it also wasn't worked.
How can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all text from the node *including nested nodes* with the [`Element.get_text()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
[el.get_text() for el in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": 'lts-txt2'})]
```

This produces a list with the textual content of each such a `div`, wether or not there is a nested `div` inside.

You could also use the [CSS selector `Element.select()` function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select the nested div:

```
soup.select('div.lts-txt2 > div')
```